# Using external nuget as a dependency while creating own nuget, assembly outside lib folder

Tags: c#, nuget

I am using an external nuget lets say "NugetA" in my project and packing that project into a nuget say "NugetB". Some dlls in NugetA are not in 'lib' folder instead they are in 'build' folder. When creating the NugetB, all those dlls get into 'content' folder instead of going to 'lib' folder of NugetB. What should be done to make those dlls go into lib folder instead?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does the nuspec file look like? Are the libs (ProjectA nuget) copied to the output folder when building ProjectB?

Comment: I tried adding <files> section in the nuspec but apparently that doesn't get used when you are packing using .csproj and I still want to use .csproj. And yeah the libs are copied to the bin of project B

Comment: Bad news, you need to use a nuspec for something like this, if the libs are not part of nugets themselves :)